# List the current OS users of Linux VM on Azure Cloud

Tags: linux, metadata, cloud, azure-cli

I want to add the multiple users on my Linux VM on Azure cloud, i could find the instruction on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/user?view=azure-cli-latest, however strangely enough there's no such command to list the current OS users.

My requirement is to create and delete users, hence, i would like to pull the list of existing OS users and then perform some comparison before deleting or updating them.

FYI - On GCP i could pull the metadata in json format which shows all users with their ssh public keys.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can create and delete the users for the Linux VM through the Azure CLI command [`az vm user delete`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-user-delete) and [`az vm user update`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-user-update). But there is no CLI command to list all the users of the Linux VM. Use another indirectly way, you can get all the users through a bash command to execute in the VM with a CLI command [`az vm run-command invoke`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-run-command-invoke). And the result will like this:

[image]